# Как отличить наречие от частицы?

Tags: наречия, частица

*Ещё* — это наречие или частица? Существуют ли в русском языке подобные слова, и как у них определять часть речи?

Answer (score 2):

Обращаемся к [словарю](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B5%D1%89%D1%91&all=x) и находим, что ЕЩЁ может быть наречием, союзом и частицей:

> ЕЩЁ. I. нареч. 1. Дополнительно, вдобавок к тому же. Налей е. стакан чаю. Съешь е. кусочек! В доме е. кто-нибудь есть? Скажи мне е. что-нибудь. Чего тебе е. надо? У него ревматизм и е. что-то. // Снова, опять. Попробуй позвонить е. раз. Приезжайте е., не забывайте нас! Во всём виноват ты и е. раз ты! Надо повторить опыты е. и е. 2. До сих пор. Пароход е. не причалил. Я е. не сплю. Письмо е. не отправлено. Он всё е. работает. Отец е. не приходил. Ты е. не читал сегодняшнюю газету? // Пока что. Он е. совершенный ребёнок. Малышу е. два года. Ты уже собрался? - Нет е. 3. (при обозначении времени, места). Уже. Е. издалека мы увидели море. Дом построен е. в прошлом году. Письмо принесли е. вчера. 4. Указывает на наличие возможности, достаточных оснований для совершения, осуществления чего-л. Он е. будет учёным. Больной е. поправится. Мы е. будем жить счастливо. 5. (при сравнит. ст. прил. и нареч.). Более, в большей степени. Это случилось е. раньше, чем мы предполагали. Речка стала е. мельче. Пирог с черникой е. вкуснее, чем с яблоками. Она редко улыбается, а смеётся е. реже. II. союз. Указывает на предположительность условия или на его соотносительность с чем-л.; в какой-то мере, хоть. Ты е. счастливо отделался! По сравнению с нашим, ваш двор е. чистый. У вас тут е. тихо, не то, что у нас. III. частица. 1. Употр. при местоимениях и наречиях для подчёркивания какого-л. признака, факта, для придания выразительности высказываемому. Когда он е. явится! Как е. рады-то будем! Ты Мишу не видел? - Какого е. Мишу? 2. Употр. для уточнения, подчёркивания какого-л. признака, факта. Помнишь, высокий такой, е. на заводе у нас работал? Там, где е. наличники на окнах резные, там он и живёт. // (при уточнении времени действия). Не дальше как..., всего только. Е. вчера я об этом и не думал. Е. только четыре часа, а уже светает. ◊ А ещё... Употр. для выражения осуждения, упрёка, иронии. Совсем о сыне не думает, а ещё мать! Вот ещё! Разг. Употр. для выражения резкого несогласия с кем-л., отрицательного отношения к кому-л. Пойдёшь за меня замуж? - Вот ещё! Ещё бы. 1. Конечно, да, само собой разумеется. -2. Было бы нехорошо, неверно, непонятно, если бы. Ещё бы ты был недоволен! Ещё и ещё. Всё в большом количестве. Речка делится на два притока, потом ещё и ещё. Ещё какой! Удивительный, из ряда вон выходящий. Он умница, ещё какой умница! Ещё ничего. Довольно хорошо, терпимо (в сравнении с худшим). Ещё тот (та, то, те). Разг.-сниж. О том, кто выделяется своими (обычно отрицательными) качествами. Он ещё тот мошенник! Ещё чего! Разг. Выражение резкого несогласия, протеста, недовольства чем-л. Придёшь сегодня к шести! - Ещё чего!

Comment: еще не золотая еще какая часть речи?

Comment: Например, такое предложение: "Эта осень еще не золотая" (До сих пор не золотая). Тут наречие (см п. I..2).